# python while going to sleep for some seconds

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am quite new Python programmer, even if I am an oldtimer programmer in C#, and I am trying to develop a realtime clock thath will be used in a display for a simple stopwatch.

In C# on a basic PC, I need only a simple loop and this works fine. But now I am on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and I am having some problems.

This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        while True:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if now.second != datetime.datetime.now().second:
                print(now)
                time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

The expected output was a new line every second, but it isn't:

```
2019-02-09 19:33:56.999996
2019-02-09 19:33:57.999999
2019-02-09 19:33:58.999998
2019-02-09 19:34:00.999989
2019-02-09 19:34:01.999999
2019-02-09 19:34:02.999999
2019-02-09 19:34:03.999994
2019-02-09 19:34:07.999989
2019-02-09 19:34:08.999998
2019-02-09 19:34:11.999993
2019-02-09 19:34:12.999993
2019-02-09 19:34:13.999993
```

As you can see at 19.34.58, it seems to be going to sleep for a second and, at 19.34.08, for 3 seconds.

Is there any way to avoid this?

The problem is very more visible if I try to intercept an GPIO interrupt: the timestamp of the event sometimes has a 2 or 3 seconds delay.

Any suggest?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines...

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if now.second != datetime.datetime.now().second:
    print(now)
```

... will print `now` only when two consecutive calls to `datetime.datetime.now()` did not land in the same second.

As your output demonstrates, this sometimes fails if the second increment does not land between both of those calls.

### Sychronized counter

A counter which stays synchronized with `datetime` can be built like this.

```
import datetime
import time

precision = 0.1

previous = datetime.datetime.now()
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if previous.second != now.second:
        print(now)
        previous = now
    time.sleep(precision)
```

#### Output

```
2019-02-09 14:32:13.070108
2019-02-09 14:32:14.001819
2019-02-09 14:32:15.033610
2019-02-09 14:32:16.065388
2019-02-09 14:32:17.089926
2019-02-09 14:32:18.021687
2019-02-09 14:32:19.053557
```

Answer (score 0):

You reset `now` far too often:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    while True: # keep the 'now' until one second ticked by:
        if now.second != datetime.datetime.now().second:
            print(now)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            break # get the next now ...
```

That you get any output at all is luck .... the second must tick over in the timespan between

> ```
> now = datetime.datetime.now()                       # this line
> if now.second != datetime.datetime.now().second:    # and this line
> ```